# From LaTeX to reST

Tags: matrices, restructured-text

While using reST (restructuredtext) to produce some mathematical documents I could not find documentation regarding multidimensional matrices.

1. How do you create matrices in reST?
2. Is there is a quick, syntactical transformation between LaTeX and reST?

Comment: Could we have a reference for reST?

Comment: Propably means http://docutils.sourceforge.net/rst.html The first question seems off topic.

Comment: Have you considered `pandoc`?

Comment: Your 1. is off-topic here. The site is about (La)TeX not reST or other formats. The 2. point might be marginally on-topic, but I personally don't think so. The question might be better asked on another stackexchange site.

Comment: @Raphink: You should turn that into an answer.

Comment: Daniel, if Raphink's answer solved your problem, you may accept his answer by clicking the checkmark on the left side, thereby marking the question as "solved", and awarding some points to both Raphink and yourself.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to its description, `pandoc` can convert between:

> markdown and (subsets of)
>   reStructuredText, HTML, and LaTeX; and
>   it can  write plain text, markdown,
>   reStructuredText, HTML, LaTeX,
>   ConTeXt,  RTF, DocBook XML,
>   OpenDocument XML, ODT, GNU Texinfo,
>   MediaWiki markup,  groff man pages,
>   and S5 HTML slide shows.

It will happily convert from ReST to LaTeX. The contrary though, will be harder, just as it would be with other formats such as markdown, because LaTeX is much more finegrained than ReST. `pandoc` will convert basic things like `\textit`, `\chapter`, `\verb` and such, but don't expect it to do any advanced things or to be able to support LaTeX packages.

I've used mardown with `pandoc` in the past to generate LaTeX. `pandoc` allows you to include some LaTeX inside the markdown documents (and maybe also in ReST documents, I haven't tried). This would allow to do your matrixes while keeping most of the document in ReST.

That said, I ended up switching to full LaTeX when there were just too much LaTeX in my markdown files.